# StandardError not being caught with ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm running ActiveStorage direct upload on a form and when the form gets submitted it uploads to S3. I have a check in a service object that checks to see if the file is too large even after getting past some javascript that checks the size. If it is, the file is deleted off S3 and I remove the ActiveStorage::Blob from my database (for technical constraints). When I run the following code:

```
def blob
    @blob ||= ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(signed_id) unless signed_id.blank?
rescue StandardError => error
    # Handle error
end
```

if a user refreshes the page and the form is resubmitted with the `signed_int` ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound is still raised to the controller and fails on the memoization line.

What could cause a rescue on StandardError to not be caught?

Edit: Here's the stack trace

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Blob with 'id'=80:
app/services/contact_us_form_manager.rb:76:in `blob'
app/services/contact_us_form_manager.rb:66:in `check_file_size'
app/services/contact_us_form_manager.rb:37:in `create'
app/controllers/admin/contacts_controller.rb:18:in `create'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:280:in `set_true_user'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:262:in `set_current_user'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:255:in `set_current_client'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:113:in `assign_time_zone'
```

Comment: Are you sure that `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` is actually raised by that specific line? I doubt so because you are not loading any record in that line. Please share the full error message and the stack trace from your log file. Btw. memoization in an instance of an active record object (like you did in your example) will not survive a page reload.

Comment: @spickermann `ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed` is a very thin wrapper around the usual ActiveRecord `find` method so `find_signed` can raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. The stack trace would be helpful though.

Comment: @mu-is-too-short updated with stack trace

Comment: Are you sure that the `blob` method in your question is the `blob` method that you're calling in `ContactUsFormManager`? Looks like a silly question but...

Comment: Yes, that is the exact line that breaks